# Yahtzee using Asciitable, need to assign player points

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a yahtzee board, but I'm walking into problems I have a hard time figuring out, my code is looking like this currently:

```
from terminaltables import AsciiTable

class Player:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.ones=0
        self.twos=0
        self.threes=0
        self.fours=0
        self.fives=0
        self.sixs=0
        self.abovesum=0
        self.bonus=0
        self.onepair=0
        self.twopair=0
        self.threepair=0
        self.fourpair=0
        self.smalladder=0
        self.bigladder=0
        self.house=0
        self.chance=0
        self.yatzy=0
        self.totalsum=0


    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


def welcome():
    print("Welcome to the yahtzee game!")
    players = int(input("How many players: "))
    rounds=0
    spelarlista=[]
    spelarlista.append("name")
    while not players==rounds:
        player=input("What is your name?: ")
        rounds=rounds+1
        spelarlista.append(Player(player))
    for i in range(len(spelarlista)):
        table_data = [spelarlista,
            ['Ettor',spelarlista[1:i],","],
            ['Tvåor'],
            ['Treor'],
            ['Fyror'],
            ['femmor'],
            ['sexor']]
    table = AsciiTable(table_data)
    table.inner_row_border = True
    print(table.table)
welcome()
```

Let's say that for names, I typ "James", "Alfred" and "Peter", then I will get three columns with each name, which is actually how I want it. The next issue is that under each column, I want to assign playerscore. The issue is that, if I for example go with spelarlista instead of spelarlista[1], I will just get a list in the first column, is there a way to make every row in an asciitable a headers row?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a single list of strings/numbers that doesn't contain other lists for each row. Currently:
`['Ettor',spelarlista[1:i],","],` looks something like `'Ettor',['James', 'Alfred',","],` when you want it to look more like `'Ettor', 0, 0, 0`.

(Note that I don't know if I have the logic right due to not being in English! I'm assuming that "ettors" == "ones".)

Since you have a list of `Player` objects and you want to use the scores from those, you can use list comprehensions to create your rows from the objects, selecting only the attributes you want, like (but see *note below):

```
['Ettor'] + [player.ones for player in spelarlista],
['Tvåor'] + [player.twos for player in spelarlista],
...
```

**Some other issues:**

You should use a for loop instead of a while loop to get the names, as you know how many of them there are. I would use a better variable name, as `players` sounds like it stores... players (names maybe) - especially since you use `player` to store each player name. A `player` variable should be of type `Player` (class).

```
for i in range(number_of_players):
    name = input("What is your name?: ")
    spelarlista.append(Player(name))
```

*You currently create the variable `spelarlista` as a list of Player objects with a string "name" in the first position. This is inconsistent and unhelpful. My list comprehensions above assume no "name" at the start. Instead, just add "Name" when you need it in your table, like:

```
table_data = [["Name"] + spelarlista,
```

Your current code creates the table in a for loop, then only uses the final one. The loop is redundant.

I hope that helps.